# ExtJS 4 How to cancel all pending edits in a Grid with Cell Editing and Store data from remote source?

Tags: extjs, grid, edit

I have tried looking for a cancel or reject changes in the grid and the store, but I can seem to find anything.  Can't find anything in the forums either.

The best solution I have right now is to (re)load the data in the store which causes a server request for the data.

i.e. my Reset button has an event handler like:

```js
onResetButtonClick: function(button, e, options) {
    var store = Ext.getStore('MyStore');
    store.load();
}
```

This works... but is there anything else more efficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ext.data.Store.rejectChanges is what you want.  It exists on 4.1.x and not 4.0.x for some reason.  http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-rejectChanges

Comment: Thanks! Downloaded the version 4.1 and it works as you said :)